# Two tabs with 2 uibuttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have the following buttons:

```
// First Tab selected
UIButton *firstTabButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
firstTabButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, 42, 153, 42);
[firstTabButton setTitle:@"FirstTab selected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstTabButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tabToggler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[firstTabButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstTabActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
firstTabButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.view addSubview:firstTabButton];

// First Tab

UIButton *firstTabButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
firstTabButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, 42, 153, 42);
[firstTabButton setTitle:@"FirstTab selected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstTabButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tabToggler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[firstTabButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstTab.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
firstTabButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.view addSubview:firstTabButton];

//Second Tab Active
UIButton *secondTabButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
secondTabButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, 42, 153, 42);
[secondTabButton setTitle:@"Second Tab Active" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondTabButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tabToggler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[secondTabButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondTabActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
secondTabButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.view addSubview:secondTabButton];
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//Second Tab
UIButton *secondTabButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
secondTabButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, 42, 153, 42);
[secondTabButton setTitle:@"Second Tab" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[secondTabButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tabToggler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[secondTabButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SecondTabActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
secondTabButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.view addSubview:secondTabButton];
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

For the first time I'd like to display First tab Active and the 2nd tab.

What the tabToggler method will look like? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use 2 instances of UIButton and have them declared as properties/ivars in your .h file. Then just switch the properties that make a button look active/inactive in your toggleActiveTab method.

Like so:

In .h

```
@interface...
{
  UIButton *_firstButton;
  UIButton *_secondButton;
}
```

In .m (loadView or viewDidLoad, depending on whether you use a NIB or not):

```
_firstButton = <code to set up the first button>;
_secondButton = <code to set up the second button>;
```

Finally, your toggleActiveTab method might look something like this:

```
- (void)toggleActiveTab
{
  BOOL activateSecond = _firstButton.enabled;
  _firstButton.enabled = !activateSecond;
  _secondButton.enabled = activateSecond;

  // whatever other setup
}
```

Don't forget to release the 2 buttons in your dealloc method.

Also: Have you considered using a UITabBarController instead?

Comment: Could you please give me a code example? I'm pretty new to objective-c...
I want to toggle also some data from a table view...; this ViewController is already placed to a UITabBarController
Another reason that I've chosen buttons is that I'm able to customize them a little bit more

Comment: So you want two levels of tabs? Are you sure that's a good design decision?

Comment: if I'm tapping to the active button, the active state jumps to the other one. Any clue how to fix this?